# creating a set from multiple lists

Tags: python

I want to count the variables that occur in an AST (e.g., a+b+a should return {a,b}). Is there a one liner that I can write for each of the AST cases? I tried:

```
   def count(e): 
    if isinstance(e, Add): # a + b
      # XXX can I write the following as a one liner?
      vs = set()
      for v in s.args:
        vs.update(count(v))
      return vs

    elif isinstance(e, Variable):
      return e
    ...
```

Comment: You could take the union of sets. Also, you can check `isinstance(e, set)`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your actual question, you should probably be tree-walking for `Name` nodes.

This answer includes a variation of `ast.NodeVisitor` that passes the full path down to the node to the visitor function, since we need to be read some of the context to know whether we're in an `Attribute` access, or `Store`ing or loading.

There may be some corner cases I didn't think of yet, naturally, and attribute access (`e.a`, `z.w`) is currently fully ignored.

```
import ast
import collections

code = """
a = b + c + e.a
q = a + b + c
z.w = b + c
print(a)
"""


class NodeVisitorWithPath:
    def visit(self, path):
        node = path[-1]
        method = "visit_" + node.__class__.__name__
        visitor = getattr(self, method, self.generic_visit)
        return visitor(path)

    def generic_visit(self, path):
        node = path[-1]
        for field, value in ast.iter_fields(node):
            if isinstance(value, list):
                for item in value:
                    if isinstance(item, ast.AST):
                        self.visit(path + [item])
            elif isinstance(value, ast.AST):
                self.visit(path + [value])


class NameWalker(NodeVisitorWithPath):
    def __init__(self):
        self.events = collections.Counter()

    def visit_Name(self, path):
        if len(path) >= 1 and isinstance(
            path[-2], ast.Attribute
        ):  # Attribute access, ignore
            return
        event = (
            "Assign"
            if len(path) >= 1 and isinstance(path[-2], ast.Assign)
            else "Load"
        )
        node = path[-1]
        self.events[f"{event} {node.id}"] += 1
        super().generic_visit(path)


tree = ast.parse(code, "x", "exec")
nw = NameWalker()
nw.visit([tree])
print(dict(nw.events))
```

outputs

```
{'Assign a': 1, 'Load b': 3, 'Load c': 3, 'Assign q': 1, 'Load a': 2, 'Load print': 1}
```